# lag variable by group in r - dplyr lag does not work

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I have a tibble as follows:

```
year state win 
2008 AL    DEM
2008 MA    DEM
2008 VT    DEM
2012 AL    DEM
2012 MA    DEM
2012 VT    DEM
2016 AL    GOP
2016 MA    GOP
2016 VT    GOP
```

I want to create a "win_lag" variable. Expected result:

```
year state win win_lag
2004 AL    GOP <NA>
2004 MA    GOP <NA>
2004 VT    GOP <NA>
2008 AL    DEM GOP
2008 MA    DEM GOP
2008 VT    DEM GOP
2012 AL    DEM DEM 
2012 MA    DEM DEM
2012 VT    DEM DEM
```

I have tried to use:

```
df = df  %>%  group_by(state) %>%
      mutate(win_lag= lag(df$win,   n=1L, default=NA, order_by=year))
```

The result is this:

```
year state win win_lag
2004 AL    GOP <NA>
2004 MA    GOP <NA>
2004 VT    GOP GOP
2008 AL    DEM GOP
2008 MA    DEM GOP
2008 VT    DEM GOP
2012 AL    DEM GOP 
2012 MA    DEM GOP
2012 VT    DEM GOP
```

What could be the problem? Any suggestion on how else to proceed?

Comment: Try replacing `lag(df$win, ...)` with `lag(win, ...)`. Separately, do note that your example dataset & your expected values have different year ranges.

Comment: Using `data$col` overrides the `group_by` because it is explicitly passing the entire column. As Z Lin says, just use the bare unquoted column name, `lag(win)`.